# What is the Difference Between "/p," "/a," and "/i" in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I'm feeling quite dumb right now, as I'm attempting to code a big long program in batch, and I just discovered how little I actually know about the language. One thing I've seen in many suggested solutions are commands such as `set`, and then  `/p` or something similar. So far I've seen `/p`, `/a`, and `/i`. I've seen questions asking what they stand for, and I know a bit about what `/p` does, but what do all of these do, and are there any more `/(letter)` commands I should know about?

Comment: A command has specific switches for itself.  There is no such thing as `SET /I`.  You can read the help for a command by typing the command name followed by /? at the cmd prompt.  `set /?`

Comment: From the prompt, use *commandname* /? for documentation. Sometimes it's a little obtuse - look it up using the `search` facility on the top bar here at SO. `set` normally sets a variable to a string value. `set /a` sets the value to the result of a calculation. `set /p` accepts user-input as the value to be assigned. `set /i` - not encountered that one before - it's not officially documented. Where did you find it?

Comment: Some recommended reading: https://ss64.com/nt/

Comment: magoo- someone suggested using strings such as `if /i "%dc%"=="up"`, as well as `For /l %%c in (1 1 18) Do If "%k_loc%"=="%%a" Goto k_%%a` to fix some strange crashes. I'm seeing now that they're not set commands. What do those do?

Comment: Um - to address someone directly, you need to prefix their username with `@`. The `/i` option is applied to *some* commands, usually to mean "case-insensitive" - like for instance `if /i` `findstr /i` and `find /i`. For `if /i` for instance, the comparison is performed in a case-insensitive manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the results of `help set`:

```
The /A switch specifies that the string to the right of the equal sign
is a numerical expression that is evaluated.  The expression evaluator
is pretty simple and supports the following operations, in decreasing
order of precedence:

    ()                  - grouping
    ! ~ -               - unary operators
    * / %               - arithmetic operators
    + -                 - arithmetic operators
    << >>               - logical shift
    &                   - bitwise and
    ^                   - bitwise exclusive or
    |                   - bitwise or
    = *= /= %= += -=    - assignment
      &= ^= |= <<= >>=
    ,                   - expression separator
If you use any of the logical or modulus operators, you will need to
enclose the expression string in quotes.  Any non-numeric strings in the
expression are treated as environment variable names whose values are
converted to numbers before using them.  If an environment variable name
is specified but is not defined in the current environment, then a value
of zero is used.  This allows you to do arithmetic with environment
variable values without having to type all those % signs to get their
values.  If SET /A is executed from the command line outside of a
command script, then it displays the final value of the expression.  The
assignment operator requires an environment variable name to the left of
the assignment operator.  Numeric values are decimal numbers, unless
prefixed by 0x for hexadecimal numbers, and 0 for octal numbers.
So 0x12 is the same as 18 is the same as 022. Please note that the octal
notation can be confusing: 08 and 09 are not valid numbers because 8 and
9 are not valid octal digits.

The /P switch allows you to set the value of a variable to a line of input
entered by the user.  Displays the specified promptString before reading
the line of input.  The promptString can be empty.
```

As far as I'm aware there is no /I switch on the `set` command.